# pathForResource returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have two files, both named `GoogleService-Info.plist`. One is inside the folders Resources -> Staging and another is in the folders Resources -> Production. They're both added to `Copy Bundle Resources`. My code to access one of them is this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "Resources/Staging") {
    print("this should work but doesn't")
}
```

It always returns nil. Why can it not find the file?

Comment: I suggest building for the simulator and then looking inside the resulting bundle. that will show you your actual folder structure. My guess is your folder structure is different than what you think it is.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah it doesn't seem to be added to the folder, still seems to be in its original place outside the directory in root... How can I make sure it's added to the folder?

Comment: When you add a file to your project, there are options for "Create folder reference" or "create groups". If you want a folder hierarchy to be maintained in your bundle, first create the folders you need inside your project folder (`project_folder/Pesources/Production/your_file`) Then drag the file into the project and select "Create Folder Reference".

Comment: Correction, drag the folder you want to be in your bundle, not the target file. Then select "Create Folder Reference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources will be put in the root of your app bundle. The only time you will get folders inside your app bundle is when you create folder references in your project. These will be blue folders, not yellow.

Change your code to (remove the `inDirectory` part):

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist") {
    print("this should work but doesn't")
}
```

Comment: That works, but I need them to be in two separate folders, because there are two files that need to have the same name

Comment: Then create two different folder references in your project. Make sure the folders are blue in your project.